# Assets loaded twice on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm running a rails 3.2.11 on heroku. My scripts are loaded twice, resulting in:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-08bbde0e2625ba65b3f4d03e5cf1c05d.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs-a3266ec390218bd1ea234887ff70ab4e.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/dropdown-504c410c0872c88a73fa906195712053.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/registration-db60840d5dd61a97052f0d3fe669f478.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.Jcrop-9819495b75d1a185b32ae5bcf2b071fe.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/clean-42820428d4061c499712d032b87a19e7.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application-5a65a574df27b941748dc66c7373b32b.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All of them `jquery`, `jquery_ujs`, `dropdown`, `registration`, `jquery.Jcrop` and `clean` are also concatenated (and minified) in `application`. I don't get why these files are still loaded when only `application` should be loaded.

Here is the content of `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dropdown
//= require 'registration'
//= require 'jquery.Jcrop'
//= require clean
```

How I include it in my layout:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

Content of `application.rb` (part concerning assets):

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false
# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true

config.assets.precompile += [
  'active_admin.js',
  'application.js',
  'landing.js.coffee',
  'active_admin.css.scss', 
  'application.css.sass',
  'landing.css.sass'
  ]
```

Content of `production.rb` (part concerning assets):

```
# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your issue is that you have `config.assets.debug = true` set in production.  Try adding `config.assets.debug = false` to `production.rb`.